# Are these warnings a big problem on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So when I compile the project for the first time the following warnings appear:

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

The curious thing is that on the second compile, these warnings disappear. I don´t understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I see this warning every time i compile and everything works fine. It's warning, not error, so don't worry.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

-this means that you use some deprecated functions and it may not work

And for this:

> The curious thing is that on the second compile, these warnings disappear. I don´t understand it.

If it works, don't touch it